# How can I printf first in columns then in lines?

Tags: c, printf, multiple-columns

maybe this question seems stupid... I would like to fprintf a dataset formatted in rows and columns. I know the procedure so far

```
for(i=0;i<number_of_rows;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<number_of_columns;j++)
    fprintf(file,"%g\t",array[i][j]);
fprintf(file,"\n");
}
```

What essentially does this code is to fill up first the rows and then the columns. I have datasets that are created by columns. Thus, I want to fill up every column before I pass to the next one. I don't know before the runtime the length of the output data in order to make a proper 2D array. And I need to print out first a whole column, then the other. How can I do this?

Comment: just make the outer loop for columns and the inner loop for rows.

Comment: You have to get the first item from each dataset, and print them out as a row. And then get the second item from each dataset, etc. Or you have to fill a file with fixed-length lines and then `fseek` in the file like crazy. How big  are the datasets? Do they not fit into memory?

Comment: I figure out by running different file for each dataset. This can be managed easier

Answer (score 1):

> And I need to print out first a whole column, then the other. How can I do this?

That would involve appending to a previously printed line. And, as you may know, adding content into a file involves rewriting the entire rest of the file. You can probably guess that would be incredibly inefficient and also complicated to implement.

> I don't know before the runtime the length of the output data in order to make a proper 2D array

If your problem is the length of the data, then I assume that by *proper 2D array* you mean that you intend to pad each cell of a column to be the same width.

In that case, I recommend not to waste time on the idea of writing column first. Instead, calculate the widths at runtime. First `sprintf` into a matrix of strings and calculate the length of each cell. Then print the matrix of strings using the calculated lengths.

Comment: Your comment is useful but again I can't even predict the length of the array. It is about a root finding function. I need essentially to move the writing pointer to the next tab

Comment: @DimitrisPeponis surely you know the dimensions of the array at *runtime*. The code in your question even uses them in the loops.